# why need to synchronized on class

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

I have the following example which tries to transfer money between 2 account, I was thinking a `synchronized` on `this` is enough, I ran the example several time and found the total is incorrect:

```java
public class Test {
  static Random random = new Random();
  public static int randomAmount() {
    return random.nextInt(100) + 1;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Account a = new Account(1000);
    Account b = new Account(1000);

    Thread t1 = new Thread(() -> {
      for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        a.transfer(b, randomAmount());
      }
    });

    Thread t2 = new Thread(() -> {
      for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        b.transfer(a, randomAmount());
      }
    });

    t1.start();
    t2.start();
    t1.join();
    t2.join();

    System.out.println("Total: " + (a.getBalance() + b.getBalance()));
  }
}

class Account {
  private int balance;

  public Account(int balance) {
    this.balance = balance;
  }

  public int getBalance() {
    return balance;
  }

  public void setBalance(int balance) {
    this.balance = balance;
  }

  public void transfer(Account target, int amount) {
    synchronized (this) {
      if (this.balance >= amount) {
        this.setBalance(this.getBalance() - amount);
        target.setBalance(target.getBalance() + amount);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

`synchronized` on `Account.class` will fix this since only one thread will be able to enter `transfer` method at any time. But I am not able to figure out when multiple thread will cause the incorrect total if I only `synchronized(this)`.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine this scenario:

```
   Account a = new Account(1000);
   Account b = new Account(1000);
   Account c = new Account(1000);
```

with two threads:

```
  // Thread X transfers 50 from a to b
  // Thread Y transfers 50 from b to c
```

Thread X's call to `a.tranfer(b, 50)` will synchronize on `a`.

Thread Y's call to `b.transfer(c, 50)` will synchronize on `b`.

Note that they are synchronizing on **different** accounts, so both calls can execute the synchronized block simultaneously.

So it is possible for various race conditions to occur.  For example:

- A transfer could be checked when one account has enough money, but by the time the transfer is done, the balance could already be gone.  Resulting in the `from` account's balance going negative.
- Money could be "magic'd" into or out of existence because

  ```
  this.setBalance(this.getBalance() - amount);
  ```

  is not an atomic operation.  In particular, another thread could change the balance between the `getBalance()` and `setBalance()` calls.

In addition, the required *happens before* relationships between the respective threads are not present, so it is possible that threads will see stale values when reading `this.balance`.

---

Locking on `Account.class` is one possible solution.

Another possible solution is to lock both accounts while performing a transfer.  (But you need to guard against deadlocks, if you do it this way.)

Comment: In my example, I have 2 accounts, balance cannot be negative if I am correct, in thread `t1`, when `a.balance` is big enough it will update `balance` of `this` and `target`. I am still not able to figure out when the inconsistency will occur.